Can we download or export ETL scripts in wherescape red ETL?
I want to export the ETL script, i have around 1000 graphs that i want to convert as script and use for an assessment. Can anyone help me to know how we can export the script at once ?
have tried to copy paste but for thousand of script it's difficult.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
